# Possible for view to observe content of it's controller who's content is bound to another controller

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to observe the content of my view's controller. The view's controller is bound (one-way) to another controller's content via a contentBinding. I am trying to have "facContent" execute when content changes. Doesn't work. Probably PEBCAK. Any help is appreciated.

```
/*________VIEW OBSERVING CONTROLLER CONTENT___________*/
App.GeoView = Ember.View.extend({
facsContent: function() {
    //do something
}.observes('controller.content'),
});

/*_________CONTROLLER WHO IS BEING OBSERVED BY GEOVIEW / HAS CONTENT BINDING TO ANOTHER CONTROLLER__*/
App.GeoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
     content:[],
     contentBinding:('controllers.geoFacs'),
});

/*___________CONTROLLER WHOSE CONTENT CHANGES_____________*/
App.GeoFacsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
content:[]
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of changes you want to observe?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is, that your **observer will only fire, if there is a completely new content array assigned** to your instance of `GeoFacsController`. I guess you want to fire it everytime a new item is added or removed from the array. Then you have to use the `@each` notation for arrays:

```
App.GeoView = Ember.View.extend({
facsContent: function() {
    //do something
}.observes('controller.content.@each'),
});
```

After writing this, i just spotted a little mistake in your code. Your GeoController has to specify that it wants to access the GeoFacsController with the help of the `needs`property. But maybe this was just a typo in your example :-)

```
App.GeoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
     needs : ["geoFacs"],
     content:[],
     contentBinding:('controllers.geoFacs'),
});
```

Comment: Yeh, I removed the needs in my example accidentallly. Thanks, this works perfectly now.

Comment: Then mark the question answered plz. This is an important indication for other people.